# Can't put file into ram with secure ftp

Tags: coldfusion

I'm using coldfusion 9 and I'm trying to grab a file from an ftp site and load it into ram instead of the filesystem.  If I try it using a secure ftp connection, it fails with this error:

An error occurred during the sFTP getfile operation.
Error: C:\JRun4\servers\cfusion\SERVER-INF\temp\cfusion-war-tmp\ram:\test.txt (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect). Check for a bad path, filename, or directory.

If I try the same thing with a non secure ftp site it works just fine.  Here is the code:

```
<cfftp action = "open" 
username = "xxxxx" 
connection = "My_query" 
password = "xxxxxxx" 
server = "ftp.xxxxxx.com"
port="13266"
secure = "true" 
stopOnError = "Yes">

<cfftp action="getfile"
connection="My_query"
remoteFile="/something.txt"
stopOnError="true" 
localfile="ram://test.txt">
```

Comment: Can you load it to the filesystem via sftp?

Comment: Yes I can load it to the filesystem with sftp which is what I'm doing now but I would like to get it to load into RAM so I can process it faster.

Comment: Sounds like a bug.  You could always download it to disk then copy to RAM for faster processing.

Comment: Have you filed the bug to Adobe yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adobe has confirmed this as a bug and has resolved it in ColdFusion 9.0.1

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it might be correctable if you escape portions of the string.

Try replacing
ram://test.txt

with

ram:///test.txt

Also, you can try escaping the ":" character.

This type of activity is only safe if you are an advanced user. Messing around with illegal characters when transferring files has an inherent risk of leaving garbage behind on your disk.

Comment: I've tried what you suggested.  The problem is that it works perfectly fine if the connection is not secure but as soon as I put secure="true" it gives me the bad path error so it must be an issue with the cfftp tag.

Comment: I saw that the problem only occurs when you use a secure connection, I figured maybe the problem is related to how the secure connection code escapes paths, and if you could feed it a manually escaped one, you might have a workaround